# Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver Error

Tags: error

Trying a brand new install of Blender 2.82 on a new desktop computer. Blender will not start, instead I get the "Unsupported Video Card or Driver" error. Video card is Radeon Pro (TM) WX-4100. Default driver from Windows 10 was dated 2016. Have upgraded to one dated 3/30/2020 direct from AMD, included with their AMD Pro Settings software which show card compatible with OpenGL 4.6 which is higher than version 3.3 the error message wants.

Any suggestions? Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender. No other graphics drivers showing. TIA

Comment: can you send a screen shot or start open blender with gpu debug and send the log.

Comment: I am new to Blender and StackExchange, so patience is appreciated.<BR>When I run blender --debug-all from the Command prompt, I get four iterations of "DEG_relations_tag_update: Tagging relations for update" followed by the four iterations of "Win32 Error# (0): The operation completed successfully."<BR>Between the two sets is "graph_id_tag_update: id=SCScene flags=LEGACY_0 source=USER_EDIT" <BR>Thanks

Comment: Ordinarily when I try to open it with an icon, I get the four iterations of "Win32 Error# (0): The operation completed successfully." and the "Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver" popup that I've seen others report. From my searching, it looks like some of the the others were solved by reinstalling, but that hasn't worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed through Steam. It seems to work.